# How to efficiently clip subsets of pandas series/data-frames to range

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do a large amount of data-frame slices and to update the value of a column in the slice to the minimum between existing value and a constant.
My current code looks like this

```
for indices value in list_of_slices:
  df.loc[indices,'SCORE'] = df.loc[indices,'SCORE'].clip(upper=value)
```

This is quite efficient and *much* faster than the `apply` method I used in the beginning, however still somewhat too slow for a large list.

I expected to be able to write
`df.loc[indices,'SCORE'].clip(upper=value, inplace=True)`
to save on slicing twice, but that doesn't work.
Also saving the slice to a `tmp` variable seems to create a copy, thus not changing the original `df`.

Is there a better way to do this loop and/or set the value *without* slicing the data-frame twice?

Answer (score 0):

If you could generate a dictionary where (key, value) pairs will be the index to clip with a given values. For example, considering the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {
    'categorical_identifier': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'SCORE': [0.02, 0.04, 0.67, 0.01, 0.45, 0.89, 0.39, 0.25, 0.47]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
>>> 
  categorical_identifier SCORE
0         1               0.02
1         2               0.04
2         3               0.67
3         1               0.01
4         2               0.45
5         3               0.89
6         1               0.39
7         2               0.25
8         3               0.47
```

if I generate a dictionary mapping by index which value to clip to as the following

```
indices_max_values = {
    0: 0.10,
    1: 0.3,
    2: 0.9,
    3: 0.10,
    4: 0.3,
    5: 0.9,
    6: 0.10,
    7: 0.3,
    8: 0.9,
}
```

Notice that if you have a set of slices you can generate this dictionary by filtering the `True`  values of each condition.

```
from collections import ChainMap

list_of_slice = [
    df.categorical_identifier == 1, 
    df.categorical_identifier == 2, 
    df.categorical_identifier == 3
]
dict_of_slice = [{k:v for k, v in dict(s).items() if v} for s in list_of_slice]
dict_of_slice = dict(ChainMap(*dict_of_slice))
dict_of_slice
>>>
{2: True,
 5: True,
 8: True,
 1: True,
 4: True,
 7: True,
 0: True,
 3: True,
 6: True}
```

just replace `v` with the value you want to clip to when creating `dict_of_slice`.

Then you can apply `np.clip()` to each element, identifying the value to clip by the value of the index.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index':'Index'}, inplace=True)

existing_value = 0
df[['Index', 'SCORE']].transform(
    lambda x: np.clip(x, a_min=existing_value, a_max=indices_max_values[x.Index]), 
    axis=1
)
>>>
   Index    SCORE
0   0.0     0.02
1   0.3     0.04
2   0.9     0.67
3   0.1     0.01
4   0.3     0.30
5   0.9     0.89
6   0.1     0.10
7   0.3     0.25
8   0.9     0.47
```